# I want to Access 2nd level related entity's data in microsoft CRM 2013 workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I want to use or get  2nd level related entity's data in Dynamics CRM 2013 workflow process but 2nd level related entity is not available

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to write a custom workflow activity to do this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg334455.aspx

If this is not something you can do, the alternative is to use a third party custom workflow activity that will give you what you need.

For example : http://workflowfieldlookup.codeplex.com/

Bear in mind that if you are using CRM online, some custom workflow activities may not work in the CRM online sandbox.